# DJI sdk - sample code execution statement

Tags: dji-sdk

Until yesterday, the TimelineMissionControlView flight through sample code was good.

I tried to do it again today, and I get the following error.

The error is "Failed to get home coordinates: Invalid GPS coordinate"

I think there is no problem with the coding if I have done well until yesterday.

I tried to solve it, but I could not solve it. Can you tell me what is wrong?

I used the DJI 'Sample code'. and I used the Android studio.

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the aircraft hasn't stored the home location.  Try engaging the motors, that will force the homepoint to be recorded.

Comment: If I press the Homepoint key of 'TimelineMission' even though motor connection is made, the following message is displayed and can not be executed. "Failed to get home coordinates: Invalid GPS coordinate" Other features are good. I do not know why my drone can not get GPS for some reason.

Comment: It should be automatic; if the drone is not getting the home point then I suspect there maybe something blocking the GPS visibility (like a building, trees, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'll try to locate it elsewhere.